# Removing None values from DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Having the following dataframe:

| name | aaa | bbb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mick | None | None |
| Ivan | A | C |
| Ivan-Peter | 1 | None |
| Juli | 1 | P |

I want to get two dataframes.

- One with values, where we have **None** in columns  `aaa` and/or `bbb`, named `filter_nulls` in my code
- One where we do not have **None** at all. `df_out` in my code.

This is what I have tried and it does not produce the required dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd

df_out = {
    'name': [ 'Mick', 'Ivan', 'Ivan-Peter', 'Juli'],
    'aaa': [None, 'A', '1', '1'],
    'bbb': [None, 'C', None, 'P'],
}
print(df_out)

filter_nulls = df_out[df_out['aaa'].isnull()|(df_out['bbb'] is None)]
print(filter_nulls)

df_out = df_out.loc[filter_nulls].reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print(df_out)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#DataFrame from sample data
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_out)

#filter columns names by list and test if NaN or None at least in one row
m = df_out[['aaa','bbb']].isna().any(axis=1)

#OR test both columns separately
m = df_out['aaa'].isna() | df_out['bbb'].isna()


#filter matched and not matched rows
df1 = df_out[m].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df_out[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
print (df1)
         name   aaa   bbb
0        Mick  None  None
1  Ivan-Peter     1  None

print (df2)
   name aaa bbb
0  Ivan   A   C
1  Juli   1   P
```

Another idea with [`DataFrame.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and filter indices not exist in `df2`:

```
df2 = df_out.dropna()
df1 = df_out.loc[df_out.index.difference(df2.index)].reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Tried with this solution `m = df_out[['aaa','bbb']].isna().any(axis=1)`, got an error on that line saying `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Still researching.

Comment: @Vityata - missing `df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_out)` in first line of code

Comment: yup, that is it... And I though that I have changed my input data too much.

Comment: Just a question on execution - if the DF is about 1M rows, is this `df2 = df_out[~m].reset_index(drop=True)` going to be a bit slow?

Comment: @Vityata - I think not, it is better like again call `df_out['aaa'].notnull() & df_out['bbb'].notnull()` vs `~m`

Answer (score 1):

First of all one needs to convert `df_out` to a dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) as follows

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame(df_out)

[Out]:

         name   aaa   bbb
0        Mick  None  None
1        Ivan     A     C
2  Ivan-Peter     1  None
3        Juli     1     P
```

Then one can use, for both cases, [`pandas.Series.notnull`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notnull.html).

> With values, where we have None in columns aaa and/or bbb, named filter_nulls in my code

```
df1 = df_out[~df_out['aaa'].notnull() | ~df_out['bbb'].notnull()]

[Out]:

         name   aaa   bbb
0        Mick  None  None
2  Ivan-Peter     1  None
```

> Where we do not have None at all. df_out in my code.

```
df2 = df_out[df_out['aaa'].notnull() & df_out['bbb'].notnull()]

[Out]:

   name aaa bbb
1  Ivan   A   C
3  Juli   1   P
```

---

**Notes:**

- If needed one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get the following

  ```
  df_new = df_out[~df_out['aaa'].notnull() | ~df_out['bbb'].notnull()].reset_index(drop=True)

  [Out]:

           name   aaa   bbb
  0        Mick  None  None
  1  Ivan-Peter     1  None
  ```